# "upload was unsuccessful,request contained no data" while trying to upload a folder to google drive- Android application

Tags: android, google-drive-shared-drive, flysystem-google-drive

I am trying to share a folder in my mobile device to google drive .But I am getting the error
**upload was unsuccessful,request contained no data google drive from mobile app**

I could share the folder through whatsapp without any issues.

My Code-

```
File directory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);

        File folderData = new File(directory + "/Stocks/" + "Branch/" + "Test");

        String folderPath = folderData.getPath();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
        intent.setType("*/*");
// Get the list of files in the folder
        File folder = new File(folderPath);
        File[] files = folder.listFiles();

// Create an ArrayList to hold the file Uri objects
        ArrayList<Uri> fileUris = new ArrayList<>();

// Loop through the files and add their Uri to the ArrayList
        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            File file = files[i];
            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            fileUris.add(uri);
        }
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.setType("*/*");
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,fileUris);
        shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, null));
```

I am having 2 files in the folder test,so thet uris are
1.file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/Stocks/g/test/test.txt
2.file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/Stocks/g/test/stockdetails.xls
:(